# Is there any synchronous way in XCUITest framework to test UITableview which has large data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcuitest

I have implemented **XCUITest** in my application but, I am facing a problem when I am trying to tap on the row from **UITableView which has more than 1500 rows**. Does anyone have any synchronous way to select table row?

Comment: What is the goal? What kind of problem did you face?

Comment: Please explain the exact goal you want to achieve and details you have implemented till now.

Comment: Please explain the problem exactly,what you want to achieve .

Comment: All rows presumably do the same thing when tapped, so it is sufficient to test just one row, which is easy.

Comment: @SurajSonawane: I want to select a row from that Table. When I table on that table it takes a long time and gives me a timeout exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your UITableView is too big for black-box testing frameworks like XCTest (Appium, Katalon Studio etc).

If you want to test it, you should consider switching to EarlGrey 2.0 (or other grey-box frameworks). The good thing is you can use EarlGrey 2.0 alongside your existing XCTest tests.

You can read more about testing frameworks performance in this article https://devexperts.com/blog/ios-ui-testing-frameworks-performance-comparison/

P.S. Such big tables are also bad for users. Consider redesigning your UI.